# HTML/javascript get (and set) pixel - remote image

Tags: javascript, html, image

How can I get and set a pixel from a remote image and display it on the screen?
In other words how can I get and set the red, green, blue and alpha channels of a pixel?

HTML5 canvas gives me a SecurityError: The operation is insecure when using ctx.getImageData

Comment: Yes. But that's not the question.

Comment: get pixel means to crop image right? an what means a set image?

Comment: Get pixel means getting the red, green, blue and alpha channels of a pixel. I don't know where you got "set image from", but I would also like to set the the red, green, blue and alpha channels of a pixel too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by getting the blob data through an xhr request.

I was then able to getImageData.